# Control a webbrowser openfiledialog Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, browser, openfiledialog

Is it possible to control a openfiledialog which opens in the webbrowser

( example: www.tinypic.com )

i want to automaticly fill in the filelocation and than click 'Open'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wont work
It is a windows form class, so it doesnt work with web apps

you need to use an HtmlFileInput no alterantives unless you can use an ocx
or some java (not script).

this link may help as well
http://steveorr.net/articles/EasyUploads.aspx